# preg_replace() regex to match relative url() paths in CSS files

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm combining some CSS files and writing them to a file in a separate directory. I'm trying to replace the relative `url()` values to work with the new file location, ignoring any absolute URLs. Here's some sample CSS:

```css
#TEST {
    background:url(test.jpg);
    background:url( 'test.jpg' );
    background:url("test.jpg"  );
    background:url(http://example.com/test.jpg);
    background:url('https://example.com/test.jpg');
    background:url("http://example.com/test.jpg");
    background:url( '//example.com/test.jpg' );
    background:url( "//example.com/test.jpg" );
    background:url(//example.com/test.jpg);
}
```

Anything that doesn't start with `http://`, `https://` or `//` should get `$path` injected before it (only the first 3 should match).

**Desired output:**

```css
#TEST {
    background:url(/themes/default/css/test.jpg);
    background:url( '/themes/default/css/test.jpg' );
    background:url("/themes/default/css/test.jpg"  );
    background:url(http://example.com/test.jpg);
    background:url('https://example.com/test.jpg');
    background:url("http://example.com/test.jpg");
    background:url( '//example.com/test.jpg' );
    background:url( "//example.com/test.jpg" );
    background:url(//example.com/test.jpg);
}
```

However, [this code](http://codepad.org/UZveAZN1) is matching the opposite:

```
$path = '/themes/default/css/';
$search = '#url\(\s*([\'"]?)((http(s)?:)?//)#';
$replace = "url($1{$path}$2";
$css = preg_replace($search, $replace, $css);
```

I know you can use something like `!^(http)` to *not* match strings that start with `http`, but everything I've tried has failed (me === bad at regex). I've been using an [online regex tester](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to figure this out but am truly stuck.

This might not be what I use to solve the real problem (making sure paths work in compiled CSS) but can anyone help me fix this regex problem, or have a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there - what you're after for the "not matching strings starting with" is called a "negative lookahead" and looks like `(?!http)`.

So for `url\(` not followed by `\s*['"]?(https?:)?//`, you do:

```
url\((?!\s*['"]?(http(s)?:)?//)
```

(I kept that `(s)` capturing group in there incase you wanted to capture it, but you don't need those brackets around the `(s)`; `s?` is the same as `(s)?` if you don't care about capturing).

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?30cv4).

#### Edit:

Since you want to put the $path after the quote mark (if any), I modified the regex to:

```
url\((?!\s*['"]?(?:https?:)?//)\s*(['"])?
```

i.e. removed all capturing brackets I don't care about, and added a `\s*(['"])?` to capture what kind of quote it is.

I *think* it is in codepad [here](http://codepad.org/5TNz6St3), but just in case, here is the code:

```
$path = '/themes/default/css/';
$search = '#url\((?!\s*[\'"]?(?:https?:)?//)\s*([\'"])?#';
$replace = "url($1{$path}";
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't quite get it working with the preg_replace. I do need to place the `$path` inside the first quote (if present). Any chance you can port this to the [codepad demo](http://codepad.org/UZveAZN1) or give an example in PHP with the `preg_replace()`?

Comment: [Here](http://codepad.org/IgjzwrqC). I had to modify the regex a bit, just added a `\s*(['"])?` to the end in order to capture the quote mark (if any) to put `$path` inside it.

Comment: Sorry, that link seems out of date. I like this codepad thing but I seem to suck at usin it! I'll put the code in my answer instead.

Comment: Ok, have updated the answer with the code and (hopefully) a new working codepad link (that's a cool site!)

Comment: Updated your link (it wasn't saved), thanks a ton, this is working! I still don't get what the `?` does in `?!`, or what the first `?:` is for in the `(?:https?:)`.

Comment: A `(?:regex here)` is just like `(regex here)` except that the bracket isn't saved. It's called a non-capturing bracket. If I used `(https?)` then `$1` would have `http` or `https` in it and `$2` would have the quote mark. By using `(?:https?)`, whatever is in that bracket is not saved, and `$1` has the quote mark in it.

Comment: As for `(?!regex)`, that is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It means "don't match `regex`".  More specifically, `regex1(?!regex2)`, means "match `regex1`, *only if* it *isn't* followed by `regex2`".

Comment: So helpful, thanks a lot. This all makes complete sense to me now.

Answer (score 4):

This pregmatch is as good as selected answer, but also supports raw data

```
'#url\((?!\s*([\'"]?(((?:https?:)?//)|(?:data\:?:))))\s*([\'"])?#'
```

Here are the building blocks of that long regular expression

```
$absoluteUrl = '((?:https?:)?//)';
$rawData = '(?:data\:?:)';
$relativeUrl = '\s*([\'"]?((' . $absoluteUrl . ')|(' . $rawData . ')))';
$search = '#url\((?!' . $relativeUrl . ')\s*([\'"])?#';
$replace = "url($6{$path}";
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $css);
```

Full example

http://codepad.org/NDoya4NC

Comment: could you possibly extend this one to also fix the path for this 

../images/image.jpg or  ../../images/image.jpg

Comment: It is working with ../.. as expected. I've just updated an example http://codepad.org/NDoya4NC

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with the following pattern (based on other answers here):

```
url\s*\(\s*[\'"]?(?!(((?:https?:)?\/\/)|(?:data\:?:)))([^\'"\)]+)[\'"]?\s*\)
```

The PHP to get it to run is:

```
$path = '/themes/default/css/';
$search = '%url\s*\(\s*[\\\'"]?(?!(((?:https?:)?\/\/)|(?:data:?:)))([^\\\'")]+)[\\\'"]?\s*\)%';
$replace = 'url("' . $path  . '/$3")';
$css = preg_replace($search, $replace, $css);
```

- allows spaces around the brackets
- supports the negative lookahead for http, https, data, "//"
- inserts quotes around the replaced asset

Test available here: https://regex101.com/r/zT2gM9/1

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
$sBaseUrl = 'http://example.com/';
$sCss = preg_replace_callback(
    '|url\s*\(\s*[\'"]?([^\'"\)]+)[\'"]\s*\)|',
    function($aMatches) use ($sBaseUrl) {
        return 'url("'. $sBaseUrl . trim($aMatches[1]). '")';
    },
    $sCss
);
print $sCss;
```

Comment: it worked with a ? after the closing quote - `url\s*\(\s*[\'"]?([^\'"\)]+)[\'"]?\s*\)`