# Regular Expression to Convert Relative URLs to Absolute URLs in CSS

Tags: php, css, regex

I am combining multiple CSS files into one (the hierarchy of the CSS files is variant), so I need to convert relative URLs in CSS files to absolute URLs.

Below is the requirement;

```
CSS file URL: http://example.com/template/default/css/style.css
Domain: http://example.com
```

Input

```
#test {
    background:url(../images/test.jpg);
    background:url( 'test.jpg' );
    background:url("../../common/test.jpg"  );
    background:url(http://example.com/test.jpg);
    background:url('https://example.com/test.jpg');
    background:url( '//example.com/test.jpg' );
    background:url( "//example.com/test.jpg" );
    background:url(//example.com/test.jpg);
}
```

Required Output

```
#test {
    background:url(http://example.com/template/default/images/test.jpg);
    background:url( 'http://example.com/template/default/css/test.jpg' );
    background:url("http://example.com/template/common/test.jpg"  );
    background:url(http://example.com/test.jpg);
    background:url('https://example.com/test.jpg');
    background:url( '//example.com/test.jpg' );
    background:url( "//example.com/test.jpg" );
    background:url(//example.com/test.jpg);
}
```

Please note the `../` and `../../` for relative paths.

I have tried the similar solutions from [preg_replace() regex to match relative url() paths in CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798378/preg-replace-regex-to-match-relative-url-paths-in-css-files) but that're a different and I am not getting it to work for my situation.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Please, mark the answer if it was correct or give an update on the answer...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple. If you want to load any file, image, etc. on an HTML page, you **must** use `/` so any URL will be `domain.com/URL`.

Your CSS should be:

```
#test {
    background:url(/test.jpg);
    background:url(/template/default/images/test.jpg);
}
```

This works for any file: CSS, JS file, Link in `<a>` tag, etc.

---

**EDIT**

So, you must use php to do this. I recommend you to create your own function/class that reads the root path of the file (here would be `http://example.com/template/default/css/`) and then explode the path you give, if you recive `..` go back one folder (delete `css/` in this case) and the add the other parts that are not `..`.

Really simple and straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for, I need to convert relative urls (relative to css file) to absolute form, basically I will input a css file with relative urls and it will output the file with absolute urls.